# What does this notation for ODEs mean?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have recently found a set of exercises which ask to "consider the following two systems of nonlinear diff. equations". 
$$x'(t) = -y(t)\pm x^3(t)$$
$$y'(t) = x(t) \pm y^3(t)$$

I don't understand this notation, which worries me.

Say in the first one, if $x$ is real-valued, then $x'$ is as well and I don't understand how to read the $\pm$, which gives me two numbers, for $-$ and $+$ respectively!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the two systems:

$$x'(t) = -y(t)+ x^3(t), \qquad y'(t) = x(t)+ y^3(t),$$
and
$$x'(t) = -y(t)- x^3(t), \qquad y'(t) = x(t)- y^3(t).$$

Answer (score 2):

This notation means nothing more than this:

First case: You have a $+$ Sign.
Second case: You have a $-$ Sign.
It‘s basically a shortcut to write, in this case, two differential-systems.

Answer (score 2):

Thank goodness they clarified the number of systems. You're asked to consider $2$ systems, as opposed to $4$, so the $\pm$ signs must match rather than being independent. (If they had to differ, [one would be written as](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus%E2%80%93minus_sign#Minus%E2%80%93plus_sign) $\mp$.) The resulting systems are as in @S.Maths's answer.